# python function arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am trying to write a simple calculator that takes a given number of tetrahedrons (the user enters their edge) and a given amount of water (in litres) and calculates how many of the tetrahedrons can be filled with the water. I've defined the function which calculates the volume of a single tetrahedron, however when I try to write the second one (which fills them with water) I fail miserably.

```
water = int(raw_input("water:"))  #Enter the amount of water in litres
n = raw_input("Enter the number of tetrahedrons:")
tetrahedrons = []
for i in range(int(n)):
    edge = raw_input("Enter the edge of a tetrahedron:")
    tetrahedrons.append(int(edge))
    tetrahedrons.sort()

#full_tetrahedrons = 0  # counter for the full tetrahedrons

def fill_tetrahedron(num):
    volume = (int(num) ** 3) // (6.0 * (2 ** 0.5))
    volume_in_l = volume / 1000

def tetrahedron_filled(tetrahedrons, water):
    if water >= 0:
        for number in tetrahedrons:
            value = fill_tetrahedron(number)
            water = water - value
            full_tetrahedrons = 0
            full_tetrahedrons += 1
        return full_tetrahedrons

print tetrahedron_filled(tetrahedrons, water)
```

EDIT:

OK, I've fixed my mistake with the arguments, but now whatever values I enter, I always get 1 as an answer.

Comment: You've defined `tetrahedron_filled` to require two arguments, and you're calling it with only one argument.

Comment: Presumably you meant to do `print tetrahedron_filled(tetrahedrons, water)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're only passing one argument to the function `tetrahedron_filled()`.

That function takes two arguments - `tetrahedrons` and `water`.

Comment: @David Robinson Thank you! I am very clumsy..

I now get a different error :D

`File "new11.py", line 24, in tetrahedron_filled
  full_tetrahedrons += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'full_tetrahedrons' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @Anton: Move the `full_tetrahedrons = 0` outside the loop so it's right before the `for number in tetrahedrons:`, otherwise it will always be `1` when you return its value.